# Crop image inside border (remove everything outside)

Tags: javascript, imagemagick

I have hexagon image with parts from other close hexagons. Because the image by default is square, but hexagon is, well, hexagon.
It looks like this:

[image: j]

But I'd like to remove those triangles outside the border to keep the hexagon with transparent background.
I've tried with [autotrim](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autotrim/index.php) script and tried different combinations of imagemagick commands, which have the goal to extend white border and replace white color to transparent.

`convert base.png -fuzz 10% -trim +repage out.png`
`magick base.png \( -clone 0 -fuzz 15% -fill white +opaque white -draw "color $centx,$centy floodfill" \) -alpha off -compose Src -composite out.png`
`composite -compose Src -gravity Center base.png -alpha set out.png`

And I've used command, based on [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=36543#p168067) answer
`magick base.png \( -clone 0 -fuzz 15% -fill black +opaque "rgb(255,255,255)" -fill white +opaque black -fill white -draw "color $centx,$centy floodfill" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite out.png`

But nothing worked.
So, my question is, **how to extend border of image and replace background color or how to crop image inside border but preserve hexagon form**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Imagemagick 6.9.10.78 on Mac OSX, I get the following:

Input:

[image]

**Make corners transparent (using floodfill at each corner):**

```
convert DB8m5.png -fill none -fuzz 95% \
-floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 \
result.png
```

[image]

**Crop to Inner Rectangle:**

```
convert DB8m5.png -bordercolor white -border 10 \
-define trim:percent-background=0% \
-define trim:background-color=white \
-trim +repage \
result2.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

If you need to remove the white as well as the corners, then do the following:

```
convert DB8m5.png -fill white -fuzz 95% \
-floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 -floodfill +0+0 black \
-rotate 90 \
-bordercolor white -border 1 \
-fuzz 0 -fill none \
-floodfill +0+0 white \
-shave 1 \
result.png
```

[image]

For IM 7, use magick in place of convert.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I couldn't make it work. After `using floodfill at each corner` it still have small white lines. I guess this behaviour caused by different image magick versions (I use 7.0.9-8). But thank you for the solution you did here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=36543#p168067 I've updated it and in few image iterations can achieve desired result.

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing. But see my ADDITION in my answer to get rid of the white border as well as the corners.

Answer (score 0):

With ImageMagick v6 or v7 you can crop a pretty accurate hexagon from any input image with a command like this...

```
convert -size 1000x1155 xc:white \
   -background none -virtual-pixel none \
   -distort SRT 60 -distort SRT 60 \
   wizard: +distort SRT "%[fx:min(t?1:v.w/u.w,t?1:v.h/u.h)] 0" \
   -gravity center -compose srcin -composite -shave 1 hexout.png
```

That begins by creating a mask that starts with a white rectangle the dimensions of a vertical hexagon. It rotates the rectangle 60 degrees a couple times on a transparent background to clip off the corners and make a hexagon mask.

Then it reads the input image. In this example I used the IM built-in "wizard:". Replace that with the file name of your input image.

Next it uses "+distort SRT" to re-scale the mask to fit the maximum possible size within the input image. The FX expression isn't as complicated as it looks.

It sets the gravity to "center" and the compose method to "srcin", so the result of the composite will be the center hexagon punched out from the input image and placed on a transparent background .

The "+distort" operation adds a row of pixels to every side, so the command finishes by shaving off one pixel all the way around and writing the output file.

The command above works in a bash shell with IM 6.8.9-9. To use it with IMv7 change the "convert" command to "magick". To run it on Windows command line change the continued-line backslashes "\" to carets "^".

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I already have hexagon and I don't need to create another one.

Comment: If you already have the hexagon, use it as a mask for a simple alpha composite. Ignore the part of my example before reading in the input image, and just read in your mask image there instead.That will punch your hexagon mask shape out of the original and leave the corners transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to make a chain of calls to change the image.
This is modified and extended solution provided [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=36543#p168067)

```
CENT_X="$(magick $filename -format "%[fx:w/2]" info:)"
CENT_Y="$(magick $filename -format "%[fx:h/2]" info:)"
magick $filename \( -clone 0 -fuzz 1% -fill black +opaque "rgb(255,255,255)" -fill white +opaque black -fill white -draw "color $CENT_X,$CENT_Y floodfill" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite $filename_prep.png
convert $filename_prep.png -fuzz 10% -transparent white $filename
```

As I have a bunch of images, I wrote bash loop script, which process each image one by one redeclaring `CENT_X/CENT_Y` values on each loop.